# no bounce in bounce mailbox

Tags: bounce

I don't know why I never receive my bounced mails in my bounce mail account, that I have set up at Civimail settings.

I do see it in Cpanel mail tracker that it has bounced and the sender looks like this:

b.48.56.909e941cf2aa78a6@example.com

or

crmbounce+id.23452345@example.com

The documentation says that  "If the mail service for this mail account features VERP-handling you should use that" So how do I find out if my mail account features this? How do I enable VERP and how do I configure mailing to use VERP or not? If there is no VERP than how to handle bounce messages?

My setting looks like this
Name: bounce mail
server: mymail.example.com
username: crmbounce@example.com
password: double checked it, its ok
localpart: crmbounce+11:07 2020. 04. 03.
email domain: example.com
return-path: empty
Protocol: tried both POP3 and IMAP and maildir
Source: emtpy
Use SSL: checked
Used for: Bounce

Comment: Ok it turns out there is no VERP at our host

Comment: So, I set up a catch-all mailbox where now I receive the bounced mails (filteing out all non bounce+ so only the mails with civicrm return paths get there). Almost there, but now Civimail report says all is well, no bounces happened and says that my fake emails did receive the mails sucessfully:-(

Comment: do you have the Scheduled Jobs turned on? Are you seeing the 'processed' folders in your email inbox

Comment: Fetch bounces job is active (log: Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Success (1)) and I do see a processed and an ignored folder. Processed is empty and ignored has the bounced messages. So civi does reach this but cannot process mails as bounce...as I understand, though I understand very little I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you need to test is that if the "+" notation works. Assuming your email is andreas@example.com, try sending to andreas+testing@example.com (from another email)

if you do receive the emails, you're golden and your mailserver isn't braindead (aka "not exchange or 360")

you then simply need to set up your localpart to "crmbounce+" (not sure if it's what you have already)

if you do not receive the email (and/or if the sender receive a bounce email saying that andreas+testing@example.com isn't a valid email), you might find a workaround with a catchall email, but I'd recommend you to take it as a hint that your mail server isn't made for mass mailing and set up a mail provider that is able to send mass emails and that has a working interface with civicrm (amazon ses, mailjet...)

X+

Comment: So, basically Civi can't work with this catchall mail account at all. Moving all our mails to a new host is not that easy nor is cheap, but might just have to at some stage.

Comment: to clarify: it can work with a catchall, just that it increase the complexity of the setup and needs a bit more wrangling. also, you do not need to move all emails, you "only" needs a separate provider to send civimail emails ;)

Comment: Where do I find documentation on catchall configuration?